# Stream Right Shift Operator Equivalent In C#?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, stream, double

I was trying to convert a class from C++ to C# and have encountered two errors with the Binary Right Shift Operator '>>'.

This is the orignal C++ code converted to C# (without editing):

```
public static void ReadSeatPrices()
    {
        ifstream fin = new ifstream();
        fin.open("SeatPrices.txt");
        int i = 0;
        while (fin != null)
            {
                fin >> seatprices[i];
                i++;
            }
       fin.close();
    }
```

When compiling the class in Visual Studio 2015 multiple errors occurred at first due to `ifstream`, so naturally I edited the code to remove these errors and now it looks like this:

```
public static void ReadSeatPrices()
    {
        FileStream fin = new FileStream("seat.txt", FileMode.Open,
            FileAccess.Read);
        int i = 0;
        while (fin != null)
        {
            fin >> seatprices[i];
            i++;
        }
        fin.Close();
    }
```

Now I am left with two errors which is caused by this line:

```
fin >> seatprices[i];
```

The error list output states that:

> "Operator '>>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'FileStream' & 'Double'
>
> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

Is there some sort of equivalent operator which I must use instead in C#? I Would appreciate if someone could help me understand my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static void ReadSeatPrices() {
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("seat.txt"))) {
        int i = 0;
        while (!reader.EndOfStream) {
            var double result;
            if (double.TryParse(reader.ReadLine(), out result)) {
                seatprices[i] = result;
                i++;
            } else {
               //something goes wrong
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use [`TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx) if you can't guarantee that conversion is possible. If you're sure that conversion will always work, you can eliminate the `if` and use just [`Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt(v=vs.110).aspx).

You should use the [`ReadLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) method from [`StreamReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx) (that's the right class for this job) to read a stream. C# doesn't have `>>` operator overload for this.

Use [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). C# doesn't have automatic [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii).

Translating code from one language to another doesn't work one to one, you need to find the right idiom.

Comment: seatprices[i] = reader.ReadLine();  I have an error with this which states that I cannot implicitly convert string to double @bigown

Comment: @DevonJ901 Your question is not clear about this, but I tried to answer about this in edit.

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

if I remember correctly

```
fin >> seatprices[i];
```

is assigning value from `fin` to `seatprices[i]`

in this case all you are doing is reading the text line by line and this [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/aa287535(v=vs.71).aspx)
will help

Comment: Thank you for your kind input, I will review the example.